# Ubercart Amazon Payments for drupal 7

Tags: 7, ubercart

How we can integrate Ubercart Amazon Payments for Drupal 7?

There is a module for Drupal 6 [here](http://drupal.org/project/uc_amazonpayments).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like AMAZON Payments module is not available for Drupal 7. No discussion about D7 port also happening.

If you are interested in writing D7 port for commerce module below article will help you.

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/utilizing-core-apis/writing-payment-method-module